# How to use other packages inside test units with testthat?

Tags: r

I am building a package.
I want to use the package `[mockery][1]` for mocking in my test units with testthat.

I added mockery to the section Suggests in the Description.
When I run my tests (R CMD), the test fails if I do not use the namespace or load the library in the test file (same for any other packages I would use in my tests).

For instance, let's say the following is part of the package and located in the R directory:

```
g = function(y) y
f = function(x) g(x) + 1
```

And this is the test file inside tests/testthat

```
test_that('demonstrate stubbing', {
    stub(f, 'g', function(...) 100)
    expect_equal(f(1), 101)
})
```

The test will fail unless I do one of two things:

**A. Add library calls at the top of the test file**

```
library(mockery)
test_that('demonstrate stubbing', {
    stub(f, 'g', function(...) 100)
    expect_equal(f(1), 101)
})
```

**B. Use the namespace**

```
test_that('demonstrate stubbing', {
    mockery::stub(f, 'g', function(...) 100)
    expect_equal(f(1), 101)
})
```

**Why is it not picking it up from DESCRIPTION?**

I read in the 'R Package' book one should not add the library calls to the testthat file.
I'd rather avoid library calls at all and if possible not have to use the namespace.

Is there a setup that would work?

Comment: You have to load the package, the DESCRIPTION will not load it for you. Moreover you have to do this test conditionally on the availability of the package (use `testthat::skip_if_not_installed`).

Comment: `the 'R Package' book` ... which one? If you mean https://r-pkgs.org/testing-basics.html#test-organisation, then ... they mean to not add _those two specific_ library calls, since if you are needing `testthat` and `stringr` in your package, then they should already be covered by the `NAMESPACE`/`DESCRIPTION` files. If you look earlier in that linked file at https://r-pkgs.org/testing-basics.html#sec-tests-mechanics-workflow, then it specifically mentions adding needed calls to `library(..)` in the `tests/testthat.R` file.

Comment: @r2evans I reread that section and I do not understand it like this (thus my question).
It says "Do not edit tests/testthat.R! If you want to do something that affects all of your tests, there is almost always a better way than modifying the boilerplate tests/testthat.R". I understood it as only having
`library(testthat)
library(pkg)

test_check("pkg")`

Following the two answers, then the solution is to call library in each test and go conditionally. No?

Comment: It depends a little on how you want to run the tests (via R CMD or via `devtools::test(..)`), but likely the safest is to add them under `./tests/testthat/`, either in each and every `test-*.R` file, or _once_ in a "helper" (loaded with `load_all(..)`) or "setup" (_not_ loaded with `load_all(..)`, see https://testthat.r-lib.org/articles/special-files.html

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the answers.
From the hints found in your answers, I fund the answer in "R Packages" but maybe not where I was expecting it:

Chapter Dependencies > Section 11.4.2. In test code

"Refer to external functions in your tests just as you refer to them in the code below R/. Usually this means you should use aaapkg::aaa_fun(). But if you have imported a particular function, either specifically or as part of an entire namespace, you can just call it directly in your test code.

It’s generally a bad idea to use library(aaapkg) to attach one of your dependencies somewhere in your tests, because it makes the search path in your tests different from how your package actually works. This is covered in more detail in Section 14.2.5."

In Chapter Testing > Section 14.2.5

"Likewise, any instance of attaching one of your dependencies via library(somePkg) is unnecessary. In your tests, if you need to call functions from somePkg, do it just as you do below R/. If you have imported the function into your namespace, use fun(). If you have not, use somePkg::fun(). It’s fair to say that library(somePkg) in the tests should be about as rare as taking a dependency via Depends, i.e. there is almost always a better alternative."

So the correct answer is:

- if you have imported functions or packages as part of the dependencies in R/, you can call the function directly,
- otherwise, use the namespace::function() syntax.
- avoid library() calls at all cost.

I hope this helps anyone else.
Thanks again for the pointers!